# Binding with object as default value

Tags: knockout.js

Sometimes I need objects for binding. I do like that.

```
var obj = {id: null, name: null}
var obs = ko.observable(obj);
```

Then when I change some value in obs then obj changes too. Just like that:

```
obs().id = 1;
console.log(obj.id)
```

Outputs

```
Object { id=5, name=null }
```

Is it expected? I use obj for keeping original values for edit forms to check which data is updated, and update only edited values to server.

Comment: Its by ref so yes its expected, but it should have outputed 1 not 5

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior. You passed reference for `obj` to `obs` observable. If you want `obj` to keep original value you should clone it.

If you are using jQuery you can use `extend` to clone object:

```
var obj = {id: null, name: null}
var cloneOfObj  = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
var obs = ko.observable(cloneOfObj);
```